# How to add an empty line in text file using shell script?

Tags: bash

This is my code; the "test.txt" file contains more empty lines and empty space apart from tab. I want to remove that empty space and empty lines as well but I need one empty line before starting `st^`. How to do it?

```
sed "s/^[ ]*//" -i  test.txt
cat $2 > /tmp/tt.txt
sed '/^$/d' test.txt > /tmp/tt.txt
echo " " >> test.txt
echo " " >>  /tmp/tt.txt
mv /tmp/tt.txt  test.txt
```

I am getting output like:

```
    st^flower
     p^rose
     p^jasmine
    st^animals 
     p^bear
     p^elephant
```

I want output like:

```
    st^flower
     p^rose
     p^jasmine

    st^animals 
     p^bear
     p^elephant
```

Comment: input is html file, in html file iam splitting and generating text file likest^flower
  p^rose
  p^jasmine
st^animals 
  p^bear
  p^elephant

Comment: For the [example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be complete, it needs sample data, namely sample contents for "test.txt".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've read your comment "it's giving each and every line space,but i want only before st^".
So you can insert new line before st^ with this code:

```
$cat /tmp/tt.txt | sed 's/^st\^/\n\0/g'
```

For example:

```
$ echo '
st^flower
 p^rose
 p^jasmine
 st^animals 
 p^bear
 p^elephant' | sed 's/^st\^/\n\0/g'
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: Avoid the [Useless Use of `cat`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html), though.

Comment: Yes, thanks. "Cat" creates one more process. The correct script: $ sed 's/^st\^/\n\0/g' /tmp/tt.txt

Comment: thanks,but i don't want st^flower before that it's coming one empty line

Answer (score 33):

To output empty line use this:

```
echo -en '\n'
```

e - interprets `\n`

n - outputs no empty line on the end, so there is no mess with double empty lines

Use single quotes to prevent shell from interpreting chars as end of line.

Comment: \n is not working me..any other way for add empty lines in text file

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the need for single quotes. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo -e "\n"
```

With double quotes, it must work

Comment: it's giving each and every line space,but i want only before st^